# addEventListener('scroll') to scrollable <div /> using useRef - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This is one of the first times I am actually using React Hooks properly in a project so bear with me if I am not quite there.

In the component below, my aim is to display the `<HelperTooltip>` on load and when the scrolling div (not the window) scrolls I want to hide after it scrolls X amount of pixels.

My thought process is to create a useRef object on the scrolling `<div/>` element, which then I can add an event listens with a callback function which then can toggle the state to hide the `<HelperTooltip>`

I have created a Codesandbox below to try and demonstrate what I am trying to do. As you can see in the demo the `node.addEventListener('click')` is working fine, however when I try and call the `node.addEventListener('scroll')` it is not firing.

I'm not sure if I taking the wrong approach or not, any help will greatly be appreciated. In the codesandbox demo it is the react image that I trying to hide on scroll, not the `<HelperTooltip>`

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zxj322ln24

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = props => {
  const [isLogoActive, toggleLogo] = useState(true);

  const scrollElementRef = useCallback(node => {
    node.addEventListener("click", event => {
      console.log("clicked", event);
    });

    /* 
      I want to add the scroll event listener 
      here and the set the state isLogoActive to 
      false like the event listener above but the 'scroll' event
      is firing --- see below on line 21
    */

    // node.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
    //   console.log("scrolled", event);
    //   toggle log
    // });
  });

  return (
    <div className="scrolling-container">
      <div ref={scrollElementRef} className="scrolling-element">
        <p>top</p>

        {isLogoActive && (
          <div className="element-to-hide-after-scroll">
            <img
              style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
              src="https://arcweb.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/react-logo-1000-transparent-768x768.png"
            />
          </div>
        )}

        <p>bottom</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: maybe you can use useEffect hook instead of useCallback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easier approach for this particular use case might be to use the `onScroll` prop and use the `scrollTop` property from the event `target` to figure out if you should hide the image or not.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = props => {
  const [isLogoActive, setLogoActive] = useState(true);

  const onScroll = e => {
    setLogoActive(e.target.scrollTop < 100);
  };

  return (
    <div onScroll={onScroll} style={{ height: 300, overflowY: "scroll" }}>
      <p style={{ marginBottom: 200 }}>top</p>
      <img
        style={{
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          visibility: isLogoActive ? "visible" : "hidden"
        }}
        src="https://arcweb.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/react-logo-1000-transparent-768x768.png"
      />
      <p style={{ marginTop: 200 }}>bottom</p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct way to bind the addEventListener on div using useRef()

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';

function ScrollingWrapper(props) {
  const [hasScrolledDiv, setScrolled] = useState(false);
  const scrollContainer = useRef(null);
  const onScroll = useCallback((event) => {
    if(event.target.scrollTop > 125){
       setScrolled(true);
    } else if(event.target.scrollTop < 125) {
       setScrolled(false);
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    scrollContainer.current.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => scrollContainer.current.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
},[]);

return (
    <div ref={scrollContainer}>
        {props.children}
    </div>
  );
 }

 export default ScrollingWrapper;
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, it's usually also good to **throttle** scroll event listeners, so they don't run on every pixel change.

```
const App = props => {
  const [isLogoActive, setLogoActive] = useState(true);

  const onScroll = useMemo(() => {
    const throttled = throttle(e => setLogoActive(e.target.scrollTop < 100), 300);
    return e => {
      e.persist();
      return throttled(e);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div onScroll={onScroll}>
      <img
        style={{ visibility: isLogoActive ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}
        src="https://arcweb.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/react-logo-1000-transparent-768x768.png"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `throttle` function is available in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the scroll is not triggered on the `scrolling-element` but on the `scrolling-container` so that's where you want to put your ref : https://codesandbox.io/s/ko4vm93moo :)

But as Throlle said, you could also use the onScroll prop !

Comment: Yep great spot about putting the ref on the wrong element! and thank you for giving me a comprehensive answer, works a treat. I will have to do some reading on the useEffect hook and see what it is all about.

Thank you